# I want to acess the contents that are not in as iframe from within the iframe(createde using EOD) using jquery. Please help. :)

Tags: jquery, iframe

I wish to get the id of the div in which current iframe is loaded using jquery from within the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jay,

You can give id to your iframe and then use

```
parent.$('#id_of_your_iframe').parent();
```

OR

You can give id to parent div of your iframe and then use

```
parent.$('#id_of_parent_div_of_your_iframe');
```